# fn f() -> [u8; N] performance dependent on the value of N?

Tags: arrays, rust

For a function that returns an array by value, such as

```
const N: usize = 1048576;
fn f(i: usize) -> [u8; N] {
    let mut xs = [0; N];
    xs[i % N] = 1;
    xs
}
```

Is the performance of this function dependent on the value of N? If I return a larger array, is this function slower?

Comment: Why not try it?

Comment: Since the function creates a fresh array, and initializing an array of size N is an O(n) operation, the function must take at least O(n) time. Of course, it's possible for the optimizer to inline or eliminate the function, especially in microbenchmarks when you don't properly observe the contents of the returned array. It would help if you provided more context with your question, this way we're tapping in the dark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the performance depends on the size of `N`.

I ran this test, to check:

```
#![feature(test)]

fn f<const N: usize>(i: usize) -> [u8; N] {
    let mut xs = [0; N];
    xs[i % N] = 1;
    xs
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    extern crate test;
    use super::*;
    use test::{black_box, Bencher};

    #[bench]
    fn size_1(bencher: &mut Bencher) {
        bencher.iter(|| {
            for i in 0..10000 {
                black_box(f::<1>(i));
            }
        })
    }

    #[bench]
    fn size_10(bencher: &mut Bencher) {
        bencher.iter(|| {
            for i in 0..10000 {
                black_box(f::<10>(i));
            }
        })
    }

    #[bench]
    fn size_100(bencher: &mut Bencher) {
        bencher.iter(|| {
            for i in 0..10000 {
                black_box(f::<100>(i));
            }
        })
    }

    #[bench]
    fn size_1000(bencher: &mut Bencher) {
        bencher.iter(|| {
            for i in 0..10000 {
                black_box(f::<1000>(i));
            }
        })
    }

    #[bench]
    fn size_10000(bencher: &mut Bencher) {
        bencher.iter(|| {
            for i in 0..10000 {
                black_box(f::<10000>(i));
            }
        })
    }

    #[bench]
    fn size_100000(bencher: &mut Bencher) {
        bencher.iter(|| {
            for i in 0..10000 {
                black_box(f::<100000>(i));
            }
        })
    }
}
```

And this was the output:

```
running 6 tests
test tests::size_1      ... bench:       2,760 ns/iter (+/- 357)
test tests::size_10     ... bench:      50,241 ns/iter (+/- 3,442)
test tests::size_100    ... bench:      77,154 ns/iter (+/- 36,252)
test tests::size_1000   ... bench:     213,970 ns/iter (+/- 9,205)
test tests::size_10000  ... bench:   1,985,268 ns/iter (+/- 267,095)
test tests::size_100000 ... bench:  66,256,774 ns/iter (+/- 5,980,973)
```

As you can see, the times do *not* increase linearly, but jump around a lot. I ran it a few times and got similar results.

A lot of the time will be spent creating an array and setting it to all zeroes, which will take longer the bigger the array. However, setting some arbitrary value in the array could also take time because blocks of the array will need to be copied between caches.

These sorts of factors will like cause a big difference in the performance patterns depending on your hardware. For example, the sizes of different memory caches, and the prefetch strategies of the specific architecture. I ran these tests a very old Mac, and you'll probably find quite different results on a newer machine.

For comparison, I removed the line that changed a value in the array and re-ran the benchmarks. The results are quite different:

```
test tests::size_1      ... bench:       2,684 ns/iter (+/- 185)
test tests::size_10     ... bench:       5,323 ns/iter (+/- 315)
test tests::size_100    ... bench:      18,718 ns/iter (+/- 573)
test tests::size_1000   ... bench:      98,695 ns/iter (+/- 4,765)
test tests::size_10000  ... bench:     856,343 ns/iter (+/- 57,132)
test tests::size_100000 ... bench:  27,973,952 ns/iter (+/- 5,565,646)
```

To determine exactly *why* this is, you would need to run a profiler and see where it spends the time.

Comment: Thank you very much. Zeroing will spend time. Do you think copying the array back to the caller is another source of time spent?

Comment: You would need to profile it and/or look at the assembly to see if it is even actually doing that.